# How to get distinct results by field for a given query in elasticsearch?

Tags: lucene, duplicates, elasticsearch

I have the following problem, I have a document that has a field 'xxx' which may have duplicate values across the entire index, 
I want to do a very simple thing, I want to be able to query the index using a bool query on all my other fields,

but the results of the query should return only distinct results based on xxx, my index simulates people, and people who live in the same house are duplicates. I would like only to have distinct houses in my results but the search is done across all houses

I know the duplication in advance as this is a one time index job, Is there a trick I can do to enable this feature in elasticsearch, I was reading around and I know that distinct is not present in elastic or lucene out of the box
I am asking for some advanced ideas on how to make this happen, including some clever indexing as I have full control and I also know the duplicates in advance

I have two scenarios: 
1. I want to count the results of a given query- needs to be very fast
2. I want to retrieve the actual documents - performance does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I know that grouping is not (yet) supported in elastic search. See [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256) topic. But I think toy can make use of the parent-child support ElasticSearch has to offer. In which your houses are the parents and the residents are the children.

So you will have two types in your index, house and resident. The resident mapping will have something like this:

```
"resident" : {
    "_parent" : {
        "type" : "house"
    }
}
```

In this way you prevent duplicates, you can get distinct results (houses) and you can search across all houses.